# Get resource file in multi-module Google AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, build.gradle

I'm following this doc:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Static_Files_and_Resource_Files
to setup a specific resources files location like so:

appengine-web.xml:

```
<resource-files>
        <include path="/resources/*" />
</resource-files>
```

Now, I need to get the resource file outside of a servlet context. So, I'm trying to get the file with:

```
InputStream jsonResource = new FileInputStream("default/WEB-INF/resources/" + resourceName);
```

This runs fine on Local Development Server, but on production, I get an IOException:

```
getResourceAsString: /base/data/home/apps/s~my-app-id/module2:multi-module-1.384597049666152751/default/WEB-INF/resources/query_url.json (No such file or directory)
```

Here's my GAE module structure:

```
root-ear
 - default
   - src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
     - resources
   - src/main/java (some code)
 - module2
   - src/main/java (code that needs the resource)
```

Did I misread the document? What should the right path be for resource files?

Other details:

- I just migrated from a single module AppEngine app - there just using classLoader.getResourceFromStream was enough to get my resources from src/main/resources but that doesn't work any more with the ear structure.
- I'm using Gradle for my configuration as suggested in the appengine sample:
  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java
- I can't use ServletContext.getResources as I don't have access to a "servlet context" in the service that needs these resource files. (Though I could pass it all the way in, if it's absolutely required - but based on the docs, it sounds like java.io.File should be able to get me the resource file if I know the path properly)
- If someone can just suggest the right setup in my "build.gradle" to just put the resources at a place where gradle-appengine-plugin will pick it up and put it in the current path on GAE prod, that would be a perfect solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current directory contains "WEB-INF" and "_ah" folders.

Here's how the structure looked inside the WEB-INF:

```
WEB-INF
 - <all my files from my normal WEB-INF>
 - resources <<< The folder I added under <resource-files>
 - lib
 - classes
 - appengine-generated
```

I was able to work it out by listing out the local files with this snippet:

```
File curDir = new File("./WEB-INF");
File[] files = curDir.listFiles();
for (File file: files) {
  logger.info(file.getName());
}
```

Comment: Also, the location of the "resources" folder, and <resources-files> setting does matter - it has to be the same module in which you are accessing the resource. (resources files in "default" module will not be visible to "module2" module)